# How to develop modules for the Apache HTTP Server 2.4 which should work in conjunction with MPM modules (prefork or event)?

Tags: c, apache, module, multiprocessing, apache2.4

I am new to the Apache modules development. I am working on implementing a new custom C-module which is going to intercept a request and handle it according to specific policies.
The module will be installed to work with one of the MPM modules - either Event or Prefork.

Does module implementation depend on the specific MPM it is going to work with? Do I need 2 different implementations to work with 2 different MPM? What should be considered to make a custom module MPM compliant?
I am looking for any tips or recommendations (documentation, examples, advices etc.).

Comment: Also, read an opinion that "Apache designers recommend modules to be 'MPM agnostic as much as possible'". Any take on this?

Comment: Or would it be correct to assume that making your custom module thread safe will make it compliant with MPM modules?